# String Tokenizing from file in android

Tags: android, string, file-io

I have a file stored in my phone "SaveTT.txt" . Every word in the file is seperated by spaces. i wish to retrieve each word from the file and display every word in seperate textViews. How to do this. please help

I am able to retrieve the contents of the file into a string with the following code

```
try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    openFileInput("SAVETT.txt")));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
            while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
                //EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temp);
                //txt.setText(inputString);
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

with this code get the entire string into inputString
after this . i am tokenizing the string with the following code

```
 StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString);
       String[] arr = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
       while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
       {
          arr[i]= tokenizer.nextToken();
          i++;
       }
```

with the above code i am trying to save eack token in an array. Next I try to display the text in Textviews.

I dont know where i am goig wrong. the activity is stopped and a NullPointer exception is displayed.

Comment: i tried saving the contents of file in string using Bufferreader. then i tokenized the string using split. and set eack token to the textview. but doesnt work

Comment: @Ruchika can you post the contents of that file? You can change the words to dummy words in case of security concern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the problem myself. The problem was that the value of inputString is inaccessible from outside the Try catch block since it is set inside the block;

so if i write the string tokenisation block inside try catch it works perfectly fine